# How to access Web camera from Geckofx?

Tags: c#, geckofx

I'm making an original web browser based on GeckoFX-29-Windows.

How to allow access web camera from original Web browser?

For example, access to https://appear.in by Firefox, it appears a dialog to use Web camera.
But I can not figure out a web camera access method.

Would you please let me know how to use web camera from GeckoFX?